# How to keep a Google API Active without Having to Log In Every Time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-calendar-api

I'm making use of the Google Calendar API and I have access to all of my calendar's events and information. However, I can only access this information when I click a connect button, and login through a Google Login screen. How can I get my calendar event information to display without having to login every time I leave the page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the Calendar API in Google Developers console and create an app key. You can then use the app key in your API queries without having to log in.

https://console.developers.google.com

You will find more details here : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate